# cpp The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c++, c++17

please help me ....

I want to show & return path of some of my files .

But unfortunately it does not return the path of all files ,

Please see the photo below

[image: click here !]

my code :

```
const std::filesystem::directory_options options = (
    std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink |
    std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied
    );

try
{
    for (const auto& dirEntry :
        std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\",
            std::filesystem::directory_options(options)))
    {

        std::cout << dirEntry.path().u8string() << std::endl;

    }

}
catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error & fse)
{
    std::cout << fse.what() << std::endl;
}
```

error :

status: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.: "C:\pagefile.sys"

what is the problem?

How do I reject this error?

Comment: On Windows programs can have exclusive access to files for some operations. You cannot prevent that. You have to detect when it's causing you problems and then pick something else to do than what you would have normally done. You can't simply make Windows work differently. You have to adapt to the environment you are operating in.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You're correct that there is no way to prevent exclusive file access in Windows, but it looks like all OP is trying to do is print the file path. That can definitely be done even if the file is locked. I'm actually surprised OP's code doesn't work as-is. You might need to use Windows-specific APIs to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
if (!strstr(dirEntry.path().filename().u8string().c_str(), ".sys"))
{
    std::cout << dirEntry.path().u8string() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This just skips the .sys files though. If all you want to do is print the file name, there should be a way to accomplish that even for locked files.

Comment: Yes you are right, But I could not find a way out :(